# Выбор if else внутри конструктора

Tags: c#, autocad

Нужно в конструкторе присвоить полям класса определенные значения и реализовать выбор присваиваемого значения на основе данных пользовательского ввода, которые организованы в структуру и переданы из метода.

```
    public struct Format
     {
          public string formatID;

          public int multiplier;

          public double height;

          public double width;

          public string orientation;

          public string type;

          //Constructor
          public Format(string formatID, int multiplier, double height, double width, string orientation, string type)
          {
               this.formatID = formatID;
               this.multiplier = multiplier;
               this.height = height;
               this.width = width;
               this.orientation = orientation;
               this.type = type;
          }
     }

     public class FormatsHandler
     {
          private static double height;

          private static double width;

          // все в портретной ориентации
          public static List<Format> listOfFormats = new List<Format>
                                                     {
                                                     new Format { formatID = "A4", height = 297, width = 210 },
                                                     new Format { formatID = "A3", height = 420, width = 297 },
                                                     new Format { formatID = "A2", height = 594, width = 420 },
                                                     new Format { formatID = "A1", height = 841, width = 594 },
                                                     new Format { formatID = "A0", height = 1189, width = 841 }
                                                     };

          //Points of inner frame
          private Point2d keyPoint1;

          private readonly Point2d keyPoint2;

          private readonly Point2d keyPoint3;

          private readonly Point2d keyPoint4;

          //Points of outer frame
          private readonly Point2d frPoint1;

          private readonly Point2d frPoint2;

          private readonly Point2d frPoint3;

          private readonly Point2d frPoint4;

public FormatsHandler()
          {
               this.keyPoint1 = new Point2d(-width + 25, height - 10);
               this.keyPoint2 = new Point2d(0, height - 10);
               this.keyPoint3 = new Point2d(0, 0);
               this.keyPoint4 = new Point2d(-width + 25, 0);

               this.frPoint1 = new Point2d(-width + 5, height - 5);
               this.frPoint2 = new Point2d(5, height - 5);
               this.frPoint3 = new Point2d(5, -5);
               this.frPoint4 = new Point2d(-width + 5, -5);
          }
          public static void DrawTitles()
          {
               Format curFormat = GetDataFromUser();

               if (curFormat.formatID == "A3" && curFormat.orientation == "Portrait" && curFormat.type == "Title")
               {
                    height = listOfFormats [1].height;
                    width = listOfFormats [1].width;
               }
               else if (curFormat.formatID == "A3" && curFormat.orientation == "Landscape" && curFormat.type == "Title")
               {
                    height = listOfFormats [1].width;
                    width = listOfFormats [1].height;
               }


          }
```

Использую код приведенный выше, но он почему то не присваивает значения height и width. В отладчике в переменные keyPoint 1-4, приходит 0.
В чем я неправ?

Comment: А что в отладчике показывают `height и width`, которые передают в конструктор?

Comment: В width и height показывают нули.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что Вы не вызываете конструктор `FormatsHandler`.

`height` и `width` назначаются в `DrawTitles`, и только при определенных условиях. Это должно произойти до вызова конструктора `FormatsHandler`. Это происходит?

Comment: внутри if else в width и height заносятся значения из loistOfFormats, но в переменные private static double height, private static double width эти значения не присваиваются.